# How to extract numbers from string separated with minus sign

Tags: python

I need to be able to extract two numbers from a string. I know those two numbers (if presented in a string) are separated from each other with '-' character.

```
a='some text'
b='some 0-376 text'
c='some text.0-376.some text again'
d='some text.0-376####.jpg'
```

Apparently I need to extract zero `0` and `376` in simple but reliable fashion. So the code works regardless where in a string the numbers are places: in the beginning, middle or the end. It should be delivering a constant result regardless what characters are around the number: letter, commas, periods, dollar or pound signs and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired using a regular expression:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)')
match = regex.search('some text.0-376.some text again')
if match:
    numbers = [int(s) for s in match.groups()]
    # numbers -> [0, 376]
```

Comment: This raises an exception for case `a`, but that may be a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for regular expressions:

```
import re

a='some text'
b='some 0-376 text'
c='some text.0-376.some text again'
d='some text.0-376####.jpg'


for text in a, b, c, d:
    match = re.search(r'(\d+)-(\d+)', text)
    if match:
      left, right = map(int, match.groups())
      print left, right
```

Comment: I'd replace `map` with a list comprehension - the result is then a list whether running Python 2.x or 3.x